# how to override available.phtml file of shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml

I am using below code in our layout file -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0.1">
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.available">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>mydirectory/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

But its not overriding the respective file. I am working on magento1.9.2.2.
What I am doing wrong here.
File over the respective directory is present, also setted the permission 777.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override this

```
 <checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>

        <reference name="root">

            <action method="setTemplate">

                    <template>mydirectory/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml</template>

            </action> 

        </reference>     

    </checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>
```

Comment: thansk for your reply, but I applied your code but its still picking base file. Is it matter that I made my layout and template files in base instead of default/default.

Comment: check your theme and set layout according to that or you are creating the custom extension then put in base..

Comment: I am creating a custom extension.

Comment: Its done, just clear cache and its works.....Thanks Qaisar

Comment: I also try to override the core available.phtml file. I put <mydirectory> that contain available.phtml file into design/frontend/base/default/template but it still doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong ?